# Player Id format issue in swift 3.0

Tags: php, ios, arrays, swift

I am facing issue while sending the playterId to api for notification.When i am passing array of plyerId's and hit the service i get success but no notification is send.Here is my postData which i am sending.

```
 let postData = ["message":"Text Message",
                    "app_id": GUARD_APP_ID,
                    "include_player_ids": [playerId],
                    "data": [
                        "name": user_name,
                        "email": user_email,
                        "phone": user_phone,
                        "uniqueCode": user_uniqueCode,
                        "uid": user_uid,
                        "type": "SOS" ],
                    "headings": [ "en": "Resident SOS" ],
                    "ios_sound": "sos",
                    "contents": ["en": "\(user_name) signalled SOS"],
                    ] as [String : Any]
```

Here is success response. in which it's giving error `{"errors":["Incorrect player_id format in include_player_ids (not a valid UUID): [\"15cd5666-b6dc-4764-a849-ae9fdd77be69\"]"]}`

```
SUCCESS: 
JSON sent:
{"app_id":"bfcb7368-d411-4fc5-a164-3bac1df63c6b","include_player_ids":[["15cd5666-b6dc-4764-a849-ae9fdd77be69"],["7d3f7fb7-ab2b-4843-9047-c5fe34a71d6e"]],"android_group_message":"{ \"en\" : \"$[notif_count] visitors pending depart.\"}","android_group":"latePendingDepart","data":{"phone":"123456","name":"Rahul","uniqueCode":"IVIVC578OL5PH","email":"rahul@chimaera.my","type":"SOS","uid":"mGs1zKSblyLyZALNtKw8YiGEr962"},"contents":{"en":"Text Message"}}{"errors":["Incorrect player_id format in include_player_ids (not a valid UUID): [\"15cd5666-b6dc-4764-a849-ae9fdd77be69\"]"]}
```

But When i am sending hardCoded playerId's then i am able to recieve the notification on multiple devices. Here is my code

```
    let postData = ["message":"Text Message",
                    "app_id": GUARD_APP_ID,
                    "include_player_ids": ["15cd5666-b6dc-4764-a849-ae9fdd77be69","7d3f7fb7-ab2b-4843-9047-c5fe34a71d6e"],
                    "data": [
                        "name": user_name,
                        "email": user_email,
                        "phone": user_phone,
                        "uniqueCode": user_uniqueCode,
                        "uid": user_uid,
                        "type": "SOS" ],
                    "headings": [ "en": "Resident SOS" ],
                    "ios_sound": "sos",
                    "contents": ["en": "\(user_name) signalled SOS"],
                    ] as [String : Any]
```

Here is my success response in this case.

```
SUCCESS: 
JSON sent:
{"app_id":"bfcb7368-d411-4fc5-a164-3bac1df63c6b","include_player_ids":["15cd5666-b6dc-4764-a849-ae9fdd77be69","7d3f7fb7-ab2b-4843-9047-c5fe34a71d6e"],"android_group_message":"{ \"en\" : \"$[notif_count] visitors pending depart.\"}","android_group":"latePendingDepart","data":{"phone":"123456","name":"Rahul","uniqueCode":"IVIVC578OL5PH","email":"rahul@chimaera.my","type":"SOS","uid":"mGs1zKSblyLyZALNtKw8YiGEr962"},"contents":{"en":"Text Message"}}{"id":"a54b2ce3-69fb-4006-9bbf-a6b2d453153d","recipients":2}
```

Here i don't recieve any error.
So how i can fix the above error for sending player_id's array.

Comment: What is `playerId`? What is its value?

Comment: these are playerId's "15cd5666-b6dc-4764-a849-ae9fdd77be69","7d3f7fb7-ab2b-4843-9047-c5fe34a71d6e"

Comment: No, I'm asking about your `playerId` variable used in the first bit of code you posted. What is its type and value?

Comment: The playerId is an array of string type and the same value i am passing
 playerId.append("15cd5666-b6dc-4764-a849-ae9fdd77be69")
        playerId.append("7d3f7fb7-ab2b-4843-9047-c5fe34a71d6e")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment below the question, your `playerId` variable is an array of strings. So when you have:

```
"include_player_ids": [playerId],
```

in your code, you are actually creating an array of that array of strings.

Change that line to:

```
"include_player_ids": playerId,
```

BTW - Since `playerId` is an array, you should change its name to `playerIds`.